# How can I add a dropdown to add item to my ckeditor

Tags: javascript, templates, ckeditor

I use ckeditor and would like to be able to give the use a list of Template Tokens (for php smarty, but could be anything) that can be inserted into the main editor text at the cursor

eg.

- {[$FirstName]}
- {[$PhoneNumber]}
- {[$BalanceDue]}

Is there a simple way to create a plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a post at kuba.co.uk that gives a very simple example of how to do this.

http://www.kuba.co.uk/blog.php?blog_id=15